# Words for Small Sets

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/)</sub>

---

*More like Words for Sets of Small, hah!*

> Intrusion [3]
> Aurora [2]
> Consortium [2]
> Sord [1]
> Convocation [1]
> Maelstrom [3]

**What am I?**

Checking your answer (Hint):

> The final word is four letters long

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are a ...

> ... **CROW**.

The words in the list are ...

> ... **collective nouns** of [animals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_names):
>
>  an intrusion of **COCKROACHES**;
>  an aurora of **POLAR BEARS**;
>  a consortium of **OCTOPUSES**;
>  a sord of **MALLARDS**;
>  a convocation of **EAGLES**;
>  a maelstrom of **SALAMANDERS**.

It looks as if the numbers ...

> ... described positions. But if we take the [n]th letter from each word, we get **COCMEL**, which doesn't have four letters and isn't really a word.

But there's an important hint:

> *More like Words for Sets of Small, hah!*. — The [useful list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_names) of animal names also lists the names for young animals of each species:
>
>  cockroach    ↠ **NYMPH** [3]
>  polar bear   ↠ **CUB** [2]
>  octopus      ↠ **FRY** [2]
>  mallard      ↠ **DUCKLING** [1]
>  eagle        ↠ **EAGLET** [1]
>  salamander   ↠ **LARVA** [3]
>
>  The letters at the given positions in the names for the young spell **MURDER**.

And that's ...

> ... famously the collective noun for **CROWS**.

Comment: Correct, and a great answer to top it off too!

Comment: Ah, I've been stuck on this one all morning, unable to find my way past your third spoiler here - very relieved you found the answer, finally I can let my mind rest! :)

Comment: *And* I stumped Stiv? Wow, what an honor :)

Comment: Thanks, @Stiv. When I saw the puzzle, I thought: easy-peasy, I know what it is and then ground to a halt at the same spot. I had an inkling what the final answer would be but couldn't see how to get there. I'm glad it wasn't a write-in; good puzzle!

Comment: Oh, and may I suggest to add rot13(n crecyrkvba bs chmmyref) to the canon. `:)`